# Giving ID's To Labels With corresponding buttons in Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, tkinter

What I am looking to do is to grab text from a txt file example:

```
example.txt:
      -line1
      -line2
      -line3 etc
```

Then it reads out each line as an individual label which I have already achieved.

```
from tkinter import *
y = 0
index = 0
root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(width=500, height=500)
canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
label_list = []
for line in open('example.txt'):
    a1 = open('example.txt')
    print(line)
    label_list.append(Label(text=line))
    canvas.create_window(0,y, anchor="nw", window=label_list[index])
    index += 1
    y += 20
mainloop()
```

But now what I need is some way to assign an ID to each Label, to where for example it generates a button next to it, to remove it, or maybe change its color, or pop opens another little window with information about the object, just examples of ways where an ID would be needed.

**What I've Tried.** 
**.** I've tried having it to where each time it read a new line, it would create a label a button, then append a function to another python file, then I would import that file, and assign the "command" of the button to that functions. But that didn't seem to work.

---

**.** I've tried using my little index variable to use that as an ID but I still had the issue of creating the button with a command that would link to a new function.

Comment: I think a possible solution can be that instead of trying to assign each label an id you can use the label list you defined and loop over it to get the x and y of each of the labels and add some to the x coordinate to get an x and y coord for the button to be placed.

Comment: Also is it essential for your code to include a canvas if not then it might be easier to pull this out using a normal tkinter window, where you place labels using x and y coordinates and maybe store those.

Comment: @MatrixProgrammer Making the buttons on in the window would be easy It would just be using the same y value that the current label that's being created has, and just shifting the x over to like 25 or 50, but the problem remains how then can I alter the label using the button, cause I still need a way to assign it a function that correlates to the label it's next to. And It's relatively a necessity that it's a canvas, as it allows me to have backgrounds, create shapes, and be able to use coordinates, or a coordinate system I create, rather than rows and columns.

Comment: @MatrixProgrammer Because as far as I know these Tkinter elements can't really talk to each other, they can't see each other, as to why I was maybe thinking of some ID system to compensate for this. Or maybe there is some sort of "ray casting", maybe to where the buttons trigger a function, and it just get's the position of your mouse and see which stored coordinate  in a list (x,y )paired with the index value for the label list, the cursor is closest to, but I don't know if there even is cursor detection like that, cause I couldn't find anything about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a rough version as it detects more around the label than directly on it, but it works, I've managed to assign ID's to the labels via indexing and some loops. And instead of `print(f"hit on {ll[local_index]},text = {lt[local_index]}, y = {ly[local_index]}")` you could write `ll[local_index].destroy()`  and example.txt just has words in it.
`example.txt -`
`-word1`
`-word2`
`-word3`

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
root = tk.Tk()
global x, y, ly, ll, lt, sy, index, local_index, root, canvas
canvas = Canvas(width=500, height=500)
canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

sy = 50
lt = []
ly = []
ll = []

with open("example.txt", "r") as a_file:
    index = 0
    for line in a_file:
        stripped_line = line.strip()
        ll.append(Label(text=stripped_line))
        lt.append(stripped_line)
        ly.append(sy)
        canvas.create_window(0, sy, anchor="nw", window=ll[index])
        index += 1
        sy += 50


def on_click(event):
    global x, y, ly, ll, lt, sy, index, local_index, root, canvas
    print("clicked at", event.x, event.y)
    local_x = event.x
    local_y = event.y
    local_index = 0
    lx = 100
    range_ = 105
    try:
        for i in range(len(ly)):
            lyx = ly[local_index]
            if -25 <= lyx - local_y <= 0 or 25 >= lyx - local_y >= 0:
                if -range_ <= local_x - lx <= 0 or range_ >= local_x - lx >= 0:
                    print(f"hit on {ll[local_index]},text = {lt[local_index]}, y = {ly[local_index]}")

            local_index += 1
    except IndexError:
        local_index = 0
    root.update()



root.bind('<Button-1>', on_click)
mainloop()
```